# Update custom module database

Tags: database, upgrade-script

I'm trying to update my custom module's database table.

An so far i have done this.

Created mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1 - With the following code

```
<?php 
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
//do this for each column you want to add
$connection->addColumn($installer->getTable('emailorder'), 'number_of_entries', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'nullable' => false,
        'comment'   => 'Number Of Entries',
    ));
```

Ive change the vertionsnumber in the module config.xml
and in the etc/module folder

Still it doesn't update my database table. What to do?

Comment: What's the value corresponding to your module in `core_resource` table ?

Comment: The Veriation number? Or what?

Comment: Both `version` and `data_version` values ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but its 0.1.1

Comment: That means your script ran fine the first time you tried, please update your upgrade script to the one Amit posted and change both `data_version` and `version` to 0.1.1 for your module entry under the `core_resource` table. That will force the upgrade script to run again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$installer->getTable('emailorder')` is wrong.

It format is should be

***`$installer->getTable('ModulePrefix/Entity)`***

Or instead of *`$installer->getTable('emailorder')`* use the table name

Comment: I have tried this with no result :( 
$installer->getTable('puk/emailorder'), and ive tried to replace it alle with the tablename.

Comment: `$installer->getConnection()
 ->addColumn('YOUR_TABLENAME', 'number_of_entries', array(
    'type' =>Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    'length' => 10,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null,
    'comment' => 'No of Entitie'
));`

Comment: try above. check and that

Comment: No good. Can it be something else than the sql code?